# Vue Component rendered twice in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuex, vue-router

Working on my first SPA with laravel, vue, vuex, & vue-router. I have a MainApp.vue(to to house the whole app), Header.vue, and a Dashboard.vue component. The Header.vue is being rendered twice in the browser.

```js
    //MainApp.vue
    <template>
     <div id="main">
        <Header />
        <div class="content">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
     </div>
    </template>
```

```js
    <script>
        import Header from './Header.vue'

        export default {
           name: 'main-app',
           components: {
               Header
           }
        }
    </script>
```

The app.js

```js
    require('./bootstrap');
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';
    import {routes} from './routes';
    import MainApp from './components/MainApp.vue';
    import Header from './components/Header.vue';

    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    Vue.use(Vuex);


    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes,
        mode: 'history'
    });

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router,
        components: {
            MainApp,
            Header

        }
    });
```

the body of the welcome.blade.php

```html
<body style="font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;">

    <div id="app">
        <main-app />
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script async src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}" ></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/popper.min.js') }}" ></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" ></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/mdb.min.js') }}" ></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont think you need to import the Heading component into your app.js, simply importing the MainApp should suffice as the MainApp references the Header component

Comment: also if its a spa try removing jquery and just using vue - thats not your issue but they dont play well and vue does a better job of dom manipulation

Comment: You may try to remove your header in app.js

Comment: I removed header from app.js. I also removed all the js files except the app.js It still renders twice.

Comment: Are both the headers being rendered by vue? Could you still have the default laravel header in one of your blades?

Comment: Only one header is being rendered. The header in the welcome.blade.php There is no header info in the Header.vue only text to test it out and get it working

Comment: Is the Header component in one of your vue route components? If so Header is being rendered once inside MainApp.vue and then again within your vue route (inside the router-view)

Comment: Yes the MainApp component you see in the above code. Looking at the source everything in <div id="main"> is whats being rendered twice. The second render being <router-view> I tried removing <Header /> from MainApp.vue and both renders disappear

Comment: I figured it out. <router-view></router-view> had to be moved to welcome.blade.php